# Reversing PHP fetch_array()

Tags: php, sql

I have this code:

```
while($row = $list_news->fetch_array()) {
    echo '<div id="news_container">';
    echo '<div id="title_container">';
    if($row['NewsDate']!=""){
        echo '<p class="news_title">' . $row['NewsTitle'] . ' - ' . $row['NewsDate'] . '</p>';}
    else {
    echo '<p class="news_title">' . $row['NewsTitle'] . '</p>';}
        echo '</div>';
    if($row['NewsImage']!=""){echo '<img src="' . $row['NewsImage'] . '" />';}
    echo '<p class="news_content">' . $row['NewsDesc'] . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

In my SQL table each News Row has an `ID` but I am unsure on how to reverse the list, How would you go about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to fetch all the records in reverse order

Comment: you mean order by DESC...?

Comment: `order by ID desc` in the query does it for you

Comment: use order by id desc or order by asc which ever fits your need

Comment: @user1844933 Description is just the content of the News

Comment: @MoeedFarooqui Yes, thats what I'm hoping you lot can help with

Comment: I'm sure it would have taken longer to write this question than it would have been to just type "mysql sorting rows" into Google...

Comment: try "googling" sometimes. Show us your sql query, the best way to achieve the descending order is to put "order by" in sql query. check this http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Answer (score 3):

I don't know which methods or queries you are using to retrieve results, but this can be easily done by adding `ORDER BY ID DESC` to the end of your SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Select` Query

```
select * from `your_table` order by `id` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

add in your query `order by`ID`desc`

it give you result  descending order